# Liquibase, MySQL and multiple schemas

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Is there anyway in Liquibase with MySQL to generate a changelog based on multiple schemas?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. You would have to run it once for each schema and then combine the files. If you use the XML changelog format you could combine them using the [liquibase include tag](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html)

Each changelog would also need to be explicit about the names of everything so that liquibase generates fully qualified names.